# The center button does not work on EV3 brick

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

My son has the Lego Mindstorms EV3 brick. The brick turns on when he pushes the center button, but he can't use it in the menu. What's the problem?

Comment: FYI, the center button is usually intended for launching programs and opening the Brick Apps. To prove that you're not being confused, try making a program for the EV3 (on the Mindstorms software, not the brick) and create a program that moves it's motors when the center button is pressed. If that works, then it's just you getting confused with the functionality of robotics.

Answer (score 4):

It is somewhat common for the buttons on the EV3 to stop working. This is usually caused by the failure of the adhesive that holds the metal part of the button in place.

You can always contact LEGO customer support to see if they can help.

For the do-it-yourself person, it can be fixed fairly easily though. This is how I do it...

First, you will need to remove the cover from your EV3. This requires a Phillips screwdriver. Remove the 4 screws in the battery compartment and gently pull the top half of the plastic housing off.

The image below shows a couple buttons that I have already fixed and one button (the right button) where the adhesive has failed. You can see that the plastic covering is coming loose.

[image: photo of inside of EV3]

Use a sharp knife to cut away the plastic that has come loose. Since the adhesive is no longer sticky, it is not doing any good.

[image: photo of knife]

[image: photo of button removed]

Use clear tape to fix the button back into place.

[image: photo of button with clear tape]
[image: photo of button back in its proper place]

Then reassemble the EV3.

Comment: I doubt this will solve the user's problem... she is no longer active on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @mindstormsboi - but by editing this old question, you've brought it back to peoples attention, and they will then try and answer it. David's answer is very detailed, and was answered around the time of the question, and hopefully it will help someone who comes along later with the same problem.
Further to that, while tidying up odds and ends of grammar is commendable, ideally you would be making substantive edits/corrections to these posts, rather than fixing up the odd typo here and there, especially on older, unanswered posts :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the brick by keeping the center button and the exit(return) button pressed at the same time for about 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question . This didn't solve our problem. The brick turns on, we can walk around the menu, but 'ok' button doesn't work. I think button is good because if the button isn't good, it would not turn on.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the firmware?

Comment: I updated my software to brick and I wanted to restore the brick foundation, but it failed. Because when I pressed the <OK> button then the brick started. It’s all right. After I pressed the <Back> + <Center(or OK)> + <Left> and the brick beeps. I think that brick doesn’t detect the <ok> button. By this time <ok> button doesn’t work.